# JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode and Fortify Warns of JSON Injection

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net, fortify

Fortify is warning me that "JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(JsonString);" could allow an attacker to inject arbitrary elements or attributes into the JSON entity.

Json coming into my app is unfortunately dynamic, is there anything I can do to mitigate this?  Is there a better method to convert my Json to XML?

It says I can "ensure all serialization to JSON is performed using a safe serialization function that delimits untrusted data within single or double quotes and escapes any special characters... is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you create the JSON string from a JSON object or do you get the string from a user?

Comment: I get the JSON string from the user.