# How to resolve Fortify JSON injection issue for JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode

Tags: c#, json, xml, fortify

I have run fortify scan of my code and i am getting Json Injection issue on below line :

```
XmlDocument dataDoc= JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(inputObj.ToString(),"grading");
```

Do we have any way by which we can resolve this fortify wanring

Comment: Same question, sadly without response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364747/jsonconvert-deserializexmlnode-and-fortify-warns-of-json-injection

Comment: correct .I visited this before but no help.